# Why isn't this "ajax:success" event firing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a view with several "Invite" buttons like this:

```
<div class = "fbinvite_form" id = "<%= friend[:identifier] %>" name = "fb">
    <div class = "btn btn-small">
        Invite
    </div>
</div>
```

When one of these buttons are clicked an AJAX function is called (invite_friend) :

```
$('.fbinvite_form').click(function() {
    invite_friend();
});
```

Here's invite_friend (some values are hard-coded as I debug):

```
function invite_friend() {      
    $.post('/groups/7/invitations',
        {
            "recipient_email": "facebook@meetcody.com",
            "commit" : "fb",
            "fb" : "fb"
        },
        function(response) {
        });
}
```

Here's the relevant line that is returned from the controller:

```
render :json => {
    :url => signup_with_token_url(@invitation.token),
    :id => @invitation.id
},
:status => :created
```

I can confirm that this json is being rendered correctly. At this point I'm expecting an `ajax:success` event to fire. I have the following code at the top of my page:

```
$('.fbinvite_form').bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
    ...
});
```

But it's not firing. Any clue what might be going wrong or how to better troubleshoot (I'm a bit of a noob)?

**Additional Context**

I wanted to add a little bit more as it might help. I had originally built this to work with a form and it worked fine. For some performance reasons I decided to switch to buttons with AJAX. Here's the original form:

```
<%= form_for([@group, @invitation], :remote => true, :html => { :'data-type' => 'html', :class => 'fbinvite_form', :id => friend[:identifier]}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :recipient_email, :value => "facebook@meetcody.com" %>

    <div class = "fbinvite btn_list_right" id = "<%= friend[:identifier] %>">
    <%= f.submit "Invite", :class => "btn btn-medium btn-primary", :name => "fb" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This has since been replace with all the code you see above the controller snippet.

**UPDATE 1**

Per Vince's suggestion I have moved the "ajax:success" code into the success function. Here is the original "ajax:success" function:

```
      $('.fbinvite_form').bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
          var fb_id = $(this).attr('id');
          var response = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");        
          var link_url = response.url;
          var id = response.id;
          var inv_url = <%= raw('"' + group_url(@group) + '/invitations/"') %> + id;
          var picture_url = "https://www.example.com.com/assets/cody_130by130.png";
          var desc = <%= raw('"' + first_name(current_user) + " is working with Cody on fitness. Join " + genderizer(current_user, "his") + " group to start tracking your workouts. Cody and the other group members will keep you motivated!" + '"') %>;
          send_invite(fb_id, link_url, picture_url, desc, inv_url); return false;
        });
```

And here is what I've done to move the code into the success function. The issue is that I don't seem to have access to "xhr"

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/groups/7/invitations",
        data: {recipient_email: "facebook@meetcody.com", commit : "fb", fb : "fb" },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
              var fb_id = $(this).attr('id');
              var response = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");        
              var link_url = response.url;
              var id = response.id;
              var inv_url = <%= raw('"' + group_url(@group) + '/invitations/"') %> + id;
              var picture_url = "https://www.meetcody.com/assets/cody_130by130.png";
              var desc = <%= raw('"' + first_name(current_user) + " is working with Cody on fitness. Join " + genderizer(current_user, "his") + " group to start tracking your workouts. Cody and the other group members will keep you motivated!" + '"') %>;
              send_invite(fb_id, link_url, picture_url, desc, inv_url); return false;
        }
        });
```

Comment: Try to add `error` handler in your AJAX `$.post` request. If it triggers, so it means that your response has error. Then you will be able to find and error type in `error` handler. Also try to add `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.post` function (it is required for JSON response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add error handler like this and log the error, this should help diagnose the issue.

```
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.log(error);

        }
```

EDIT

Sorry you need to use .ajax instead of .post.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/groups/7/invitations",
  data: "name=John&location=Boston",
  success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  },
  error(xhr, status, error) {
     console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where do I put this? I'm unable to get it to work. You can assume I'm brand new to JS

Comment: Got it. Just updated to this and can confirm that I get the success alert to fire. But the issue still remains that the "ajax:success" event is not triggering: `function invite_friend() {   

 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/groups/7/invitations",
     data: {recipient_email: "facebook@meetcody.com", commit : "fb", fb : "fb" },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(result) {
         alert("hi yup");
  }
     });
}`

Comment: move the "ajax:success" into the ajax success function so it is triggered instead of the alert.

Comment: Moved and the code is now executing, however hitting a problem. My "ajax:success" function was as such:     `$('.fbinvite_form').bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
     var fb_id = $(this).attr('id');
     var response = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");` Basically I need the `xhr.responseText' but don't seem to have that in this success function. I will paste the full code as I've edited in my original question so you can have a better look.

Comment: @pejmanjohn  remove evt from the function so you only have (data, status, xhr)